# Terraform to create ec2 instance error even though instance is created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform-provider-aws

I am having trouble creating ec2 instances with my IAM role.
The permissions I gave are

**List**
DescribeInstances
DescribeKeyPairs

**Read**
DescribeTags

**Tagging**
CreateTags

**Write**
CreateKeyPair
DeleteKeyPair
ImportKeyPair
RunInstances
TerminateInstances

The error is

```
error while describing instance(...) attribute (instanceInitiatedShutdownBehaviour): UnnauthorizedOperation: You are no authorized to perform this operation.
```

However, on the AWS console, the ec2 instance is created. I am unable to `terraform destroy` it due to the same error.

It works if I give full ec2 access (ec2:*) so it has nothing to do with my terraform code.

Thank you.

Comment: seems like having all the list works (ec2:Describe*), not sure what is the least policy I can give for list

Comment: Apparently terraform runs instances before tagging them too

Answer (score 2):

I went through the same error and it is because of lack of permission. In the error:

```
error while describing instance(...) attribute (instanceInitiatedShutdownBehaviour): UnnauthorizedOperation: You are no authorized to perform this operation.
```

the `UnnauthorizedOperation` is trying to describe an instance attribute since you do not have the `ec2:DescribeInstanceAttribute` permission.

Depending on how your terraform config looks like for the instances, you may require more permissions. You can enable debug logs in your apply command to get more information:

```
TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform apply
```

Use the visual policy editor to add permissions to your IAM role and look out for
`Action Warnings`. It will tell you if you are missing any permissions required by the existing permission.